# Why XMLHttpRequest PUT request does not work?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, api, xmlhttprequest

I have a simple **NODEJS API** with basic **CRUD** actions in my controller.

However all request methods, but **PUT**, seem working. I just  have problem with the PUT method.

This is the **API side** code:

```
app.put('/api/prodotti/:Id', function (req, res) {
connection.query("UPDATE Prodotti SET Descrizione=?, Prezzo=?, Categoria=? WHERE Id=?", [req.body.Descrizione, req.body.Prezzo, req.body.Categoria, req.params.Id], function (error, result) {
    if (error)
        res.send("Errore query: " + error.message);
    if (result.changedRows == 0)
        res.send("Non modificato!");

    console.log("Id modificato: " + req.params.Id);
    res.json(req.params.Id);
});
});
```

While this is my **HTML page** (client) side:

```
<form>
        <label>Id</label>
        <br />
        <input id="Mid" type="number" name="Id"/>
        <br />
        <label>Descrizione</label>
        <br />
        <input id="Mdescrizione" type="text" name="Descrizione" />
        <br />
        <label>Prezzo</label>
        <br />
        <input id="Mprezzo" type="number" name="Prezzo" />
        <br />
        <label>Categoria</label>
        <br />
        <select id="Mcategoria" name="Categoria">
            <option value="Categoria 1">Categoria 1</option>
            <option value="Categoria 2">Categoria 2</option>
            <option value="Categoria 3">Categoria 3</option>
            <option value="Categoria 4">Categoria 4</option>
            <option value="Categoria 5">Categoria 5</option>
        </select>
        <br />
        <br />
        <button type="button" onclick="UpdateProdotti();"> Modifica </button>
        <input type="reset" value="Reset campi" />
    </form>
```

and the onclick **function**:

```
function UpdateProdotti() {
        var id = document.getElementById("Mid").value;
        var descrizione = document.getElementById("Mdescrizione").value;
        var prezzo = document.getElementById("Mprezzo").value;
        var categoria = document.getElementById("Mcategoria").value;

        data = {};
        data.Descrizione = descrizione;
        data.Prezzo = prezzo;
        data.Categoria = categoria;

        var json = JSON.stringify(data);

        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type','application/json; charset=utf-8');

        xhr.open("PUT", "api/prodotti/" + id, true);
        xhr.onload = function () {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                alert("Modificato " + xhr.responseText);
            }
        }

        xhr.send(json);
    }
```

I am able to make all the other request and get the response easily. I know that the `UpdateProdotti` function is called when the button is clicked, but even if I add a break point to the API the request is never received.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: in the network tab in devtools do you see the request you make?

Comment: beware that after `res.send` you can't call the `res.json(req.params.Id);`, you need to add a `return`

Comment: @ManuelSpigolon yes, but res.send is inside an if and res.json is called if there are no errors

Comment: @ajuni880 no I don't see it

Comment: @RiccardoRaffini check this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/setRequestHeader. Basically it says that `setRequestHeader` should be set after `open`

Comment: @ajuni880 I fixed this, but now when I make the request (i can see it) the node API crash

Comment: @RiccardoRaffini i cant tell you much without log details

Comment: @ajuni880 no more problems i figured how to solve it. I was calling result.changedRows instead of result.affectedRows